# how to show input field by selecting option in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here I have one `material native select` and in this select dropdown two options(% and number) when % option that time I want to show discount by % input field and when I select number option that time i want to show  discount by number input field how it is possible to show input field by choosing option ?

```
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="newObj.newPrice" name="newPrice">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <select matNativeControl>
      <option value="percentagewise">%</option>
      <option value="numberwise">Number</option>
    </select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Discount By %" [(ngModel)]="newObj.newDiscountByPercentage" name="newDiscountByPercentage">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Discount By Number" type="number" [(ngModel)]="newObj.newDiscountByNumber" name="newDiscountByNumber">
  </mat-form-field>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just go with `*ngIf`, but firstly you need to define `ngModel` on `select` to get `two-way binding`, then use it's variable in `*ngIf`

```
<mat-form-field>
    <select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="discountType">
      <option value="percentagewise">%</option>
      <option value="numberwise">Number</option>
    </select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field *ngIf="discountType == 'percentagewise'" >
    <inputmatInput placeholder="Enter Discount By %" [(ngModel)]="newObj.newDiscountByPercentage" name="newDiscountByPercentage">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field *ngIf="discountType == 'numberwise'" >
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Discount By Number" type="number" [(ngModel)]="newObj.newDiscountByNumber" name="newDiscountByNumber">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Also you should define `discountType` in your `component.ts` file to avoid errors during `aot` compilation. Read more about `*ngIf` directive [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)